# Access with voice match in android

Tags: android, android-service, voice-recognition, android-security

### Access with voice match in android for security lock

---

Hello guys I want to make a security lock for android, in which it will be open with some specific keyword. It is similar to latest google assistant and alexa. In alexa if we call Alexa it will popup their 
voice recognization activity. Please give me hint to open lock with the help of such same activity in android.

1. Is it possible to build such application?
2. if it is possible, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [snowboy](https://github.com/Kitt-AI/snowboy/tree/master/examples/Android) library to detect special words and then use a foreground service to listen to the user's voice in lock mode. Although you need to train a word with `snowboy` panel and use that model in your app. Also, they have some prepared models to test and develope.